# Dealing with responsivity on a HTML/CSS slider

Tags: html, css, django, responsive-design

I'm trying to create an image slider inside my image component in Django. I've got it setup like this so far

```
{% extends './base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}
<script src='../../static/pages/main.js'></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<div class="gallery-container">
  <img class="background-gallery" src="../../static/images/laptop_crop.png" />
  <div id="slider">
    <figure>
      <img src="../../static/images/logo/kingict-okvir.png" />
      <img src="../../static/images/logo/pwc-okvir.png" />
      <img src="../../static/images/logo/degordian-okvir.png" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

```
.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.background-gallery {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5em;
}
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 12%;
}
#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 15s slider infinite;
}
#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  /* 100% {
    left: -400%;
  } */
}
```

`extends '../base.html' is just extending some elements I'm using on every site and have no impact on the slider gallery

My issue is that with any resizing of the image it just breaks. I'm looking for a way to make my current one responsive or replace it with something that will be responsive. I realize this is due to the fact I'm displaying images with the white borders around them but I won't have any other format of images that I can use.

The issue further explained by this image

[image]

Comment: Possible to recreate this in a jsfiddle for example?

Comment: Yeah here it is https://jsfiddle.net/uz3t1vjf/3/. Try expading the screen to 1920x1080 since that's how it was originally designed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you started. You can create media queries for this. I added an example for 1400px screens or lower. But you can add as many as you like:
https://jsfiddle.net/5yjvzh9k/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .background-gallery {
    max-width: 70%;
  }
  #slider {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 16%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Media queries is the way, marking this as solution, thanks!